# on delete cascade and on update cascade with more foreign key

Tags: sql

I have a question:
on delete cascade and on update cascade delete and update parent table. But if I have a table with multiple foreign keys and if I delete or update the primary key, will the foreign key referring to it be deleted or modified?
For example:

```
table A
create table A(
attributeA_key varchar NOT NULL,
attributeA varchar NULL,
constraint table_A_pk primary key(attributeA_key)
);

table B
create table B(
attributeB_key varchar NOT NULL,
attributeB varchar NULL,
constraint table_B_pk primary key(attributeB_key),
constraint table_B_fk foreign key (attributeB) references A(attributeA_key)
);

table C
create table C(
attributeC_key varchar NOT NULL,
attributeC varchar NULL,
constraint table_C_pk primary key(attributeC_key),
constraint table_C_fk foreign key (attributeC) references A(attributeA_key) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

when i insert some data if i put delete or update foreign key of table C, the foreign key of the table B(attributeB) will be deleted or updated?

Comment: No, only if you update the **primary key** in A will anything else change. And then both B and C get updated

Comment: But as it stands, it won't work, as B doesn't have `on update cascade`. And generally one doesn't change PKs.

Comment: ok but can't use on delete cascade on update cascade on primary key. If i want update primary key how can i do?

Comment: The `on delete` is on the foreign table, and says "update **this** table if **that** table is updated.

Comment: i try add on update cascade also in table B

Comment: but on delete cascade on one table A delete all tables referring to it?

Comment: Yes, it will delete from all other tables that have a cascaded FK to table A. The PK on A does not itself have a cascade.